# Hibernate from i3

Tags: 18.04, i3-wm

I'm trying to hibernate using a shortcut from i3. My i3 config file looks like this :

```
 14 # Keyboard friendly exit
 15 set $exit exit: [l]ock, [e]logout, [h]ibernate, [r]eboot, [s]hutdown
 16 mode "$exit" {
 17   bindsym h exec "i3lock; systemctl hibernate"; mode "default"
 18   bindsym l exec i3lock -c 000000; mode "default"
 19   bindsym e exec i3-msg exit
 20   bindsym r exec systemctl reboot
 21   bindsym s exec systemctl poweroff
 22   bindsym Escape mode "default"
 23   bindsym Return mode "default"
 24 }
```

When I press h in the right mode, my PC locks itself but doesn't hibernate.
I have tried replacing `systemctl hibernate` by `sudo systemctl hibernate` but it doesn't work either.

On a terminal, I can `sudo systemctl hibernate` to hibernate while `systemctl hibernate` will prompt me to authenticate with this message

```
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Access denied
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'hibernate.target'.
Authenticating as: $User,,, ($user)
Password:
```

I am able to correctly shutdown and reboot from i3 but not hibernate.

Edit : I have a swap partition and hibernate functions if done from command line with `sudo sytemctl hibernate` .

My fstab looks like this :

```
# Swap
UUID=424242-4242-4242-4242-4242424242 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Just a quick question from me, but do you have swap enabled?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/swaps`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please create a new line within sudoers for nopasswd on systemctl hibernate and see how you go? 
I have hibernate mapped to Alt + Shift + F4, and I have configured my id to run `sudo systemctl hibernate` with no passwd

1. Check where systemctl is :
    `which systemctl`
2. Replace the output of the above command in the #placeholder# within sudoers and i3 config :

sudoers file :

```
midway ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: #placeholder# hibernate
```

i3 config :

```
bindsym Mod1+Shift+F4  exec sudo #placeholder# hibernate
```

Hope this is easier to follow.

Comment: I have tried your solution (by replacing midway with my username) and it didn't work. To be more specific, even doing `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate` in command line didn't work. It yielded `sudo: /usr/bin/systemctl: command not found` and also prompted me for my password.

Comment: @StatisticDean, sorry, I should have been clearer.
I will edit my answer now.

Comment: This is not working for me yet. Changing the sudoers file did nothing. `sudo /bin/systemctl` still calls me for my password and doing from i3 still only locks my screen.